# Plasma recognizes Corsair mouse as Game Controller - how to utilize additional buttons?

Tags: mouse, kde, plasma

I have a CORSAIR KATAR PRO Wireless mouse running via USB dongle and in the system settings its recognized as a game controller. The additional buttons on the mouse are also recognized ([screenshot: button 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3zXO.png)). I'd like to remap the additional buttons but I'm not sure where to start.